# Большие таблицы со сложной фильтрацией на vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

Нужно организовать таблицу на vue со сложной фильтрацией и сортировкой с учетом того, что пользователь будет работать с 4000+ записей. Есть ли какие-то сторонние библиотеки в которых такая тему организована?

Пробовала воспользоваться стандартными vuetify табличками, довольно долго отрабатывает на 3000-4000+ строках в табличке.

Comment: проблема не в библиотеке, а в том, что 4к элементов изменить одновременно проблематично любому браузеру. Просто добавьте пагинацию и разбейте таблицу на страницы.
Если любите по сложнее - сделайти инфинити скролл, элементы, за полосой прокрутки удаляйте, чтоб не загружать память.

Comment: @Evgenii Пагинацию использую, но это не достаточно решает проблему, все равно обновление компонента после фильтрации секунд по 10 занимает, а при большом количестве последовательных фильтраций и с памятью проблема начинается. Конечно возможны косяки в реализации поэтому подумала заменить на библиотечку

Comment: А как реализована пагинация? вы получаете всю таблицу с бэка и на фронте уже сами разбиваете ее на страницы? А проблемы с памятью после нескольких фильтраций начинаются, скорей всего, из-за утечки памяти.

Comment: @Evgenii Да, получаю от бека все и сразу и уже на фронте разбиваю

Comment: В этом и проблема. Вся логика должна быть на бэке: вы отправляете запрос на бэк со всей необходимой информацией (фильтры, номер страницы или с какого по какой элемент получить хотите), а бэк возвращает информацию по вашему запросу (элементы уже отфильтрованные и нужную страницу), но никак не всю таблицу. Ваш бэк ленится, если говорит, что это должно обрабатываться на фронте)